# Logical negation and assignment operator in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, operators

Is there a more concise way to write the second line of this function without repeating `a` reduntantly?

```
void myfunc()
{
    bool a = false; // Assume that this won't alway be hardcoded to false.
    a = !a;
}
```

Comment: `bool a = true;`

Comment: Come on!! Assuming that the first line of the function won't always be hardcoded to `a=false`, obviously.

Comment: @SaqibAli If you are going to hardcode it to `true` hardcode it as `false` and vise versa. This is what we can come up, unless you want to tell what is the actual problem you are going to solve.

Comment: if it's a result of callable use `not_fn()`. if it's just defined as you wrote it, initialize it by the other value.

Comment: `!` is an unary operator, you cannot associate it with `=` if this is what you expected. But you can do something like `a ^= true;`

Comment: The repetition of `a` is not redundant. The `a` in `!a` says where to read a value from. The `a` in `a =` says where to write a value to. The fact that these are the same is a separate distinct fact; it differentiates the statement from `b = !a;` and so is not redundant. What you are asking for is not a way to reduce redundancy but a way to express grammatical reflexivity. The C standard provides nothing explicit for this. You could write a macro or function for it, but most good software engineers would consider this to be of low value and possibly negative net value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible answer is: **unfortunately not**.

The unary operator `!` is actually concise enough, and any other trick would lead to unreadable code.

Any other shortcut form, for example for binary operators such as `+` or `*`:

```
a += 5;
b *= 7;
```

mantain the reference to the original meaning of theoperator: multiplication and addition respectively.

In your sentence:

> without repeating `a` reduntantly

there's the wrong assumption that `a` is redundant in case the compiler could be instructed to negate `a` without repeating the variable name. No: it tells to people reading the code (even to yourself, for example an year later!) that the variable to be negated is `a`. And since C grammar doesn't define any syntactic sugar for logical negation operator, `a` is not redundant at all.

Comment: whatever, `!` is an unary operator so a form ` <op>=` has no sense here, that form is only applicable with binary operators

Comment: @bruno could you quote the sentence in which I state that ! is applicable to binary operators? I explained to the OP why it is not possible unlike what happens with +,-,and so on.

Comment: you say here : `!=` and speaking about + and (binary) -, in fact all in your answer is about binary operators

Comment: @bruno My answer is "Unfortunately not". And it is the only real answer. The `^=true` solution would lead to undesirable code in real life production development.

Comment: I did my first remark hoping you will edit your answer, I wait for but nothing, so I finally did an answer myself (and also someone asking me to make an answer from my remark in the OP question)

Comment: @bruno usually suggestions are gold for me, bu I was afk. I try to explain myself. When a beginner does a wrong assumption I ask myself: why did they thought it wrong? And I suggest a way to understand the issue. Now, your remark was undeserved. Example: OP asks "do dogs fly?" "No, they don't. Ducks do." Remark: "this has no sense. Dogs have 4 feet, ducks only two."

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't really see the value of doing so, but you could use xor or a simple decrement. Both of these work.

```
a ^= 1;
a--;
```

Then you won't have to repeat `a`.

But if you want it to be very clear, consider using a function:

```
void flip(bool *b) 
{
    (*b)--;
}

bool b = true;
flip(&b);
```

In C++, you can use references

```
void flip(bool &b) 
{
    b--;
}

bool b = true;
flip(b);
```

Or write a macro. Actually, macros are pretty handy for solving duplication problems. Although, I almost never use them for that, since it's simply rarely worth the effort. I wrote one macro to avoid duplication for malloc calls. Such a call typically look like this:

```
int *x = malloc(12 * sizeof *x);
```

You can avoid the duplication with this:

```
#define ALLOC(p, n)  \
            ((p) = malloc((n) * sizeof *(p)))
```

But even this is something I hesitate to use.

To be honest, it's not really a problem worth solving. :)

Comment: ... or `a--;`, `--a;`  or `a -= true;`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a more concise way to write the second line of this function without repeating a reduntantly?

`!` is an unary operator, you cannot associate it with `=` if this is what you expected.

But you can do something like `a ^= true;`, this is not a *more concise way* but this is *without repeating a redundantly*. Anyway this is not a good way to do contrarily to `a = !a;` which is much more readable

Comment: Suggesting something like that would lead to unreadable code. The logical negation operator is concise enough. The only real answer is use `!a`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni for sure `a ^= true;` is not a good solution to negate ^^, but the OP question is not about a 'good way to do', but *Is there a more concise way to write the second line of this function **without repeating a reduntantly***

Comment: @RobertoCaboni as I said you I put the remark in your answer to help you, hoping you will edit it, and waiting for also to be able to UV your answer. It seems you get my remark wrong, was not the goal ...